# Blender: An object shall change its parent during an animation but the the child is offset to either the 1st or 2nd parent

Tags: animation, armature, constraints, parent

I have created a new blender model (primary object) and wanted to animate it. It has a teddy (2nd object) on its side that shall move with it when it is moving around (so the parent is the Pelvis.R). That is working fine but I wanted to add a sing animation, for which it is taking up that teddy with its right hand (and so the parent bone switches to Hand.R) but the teddy does not move with the hand (even the influence of the pelvis is set to 0.) and seems offset until the teddy is put back on the side which works fine.
I got the hand following but then the teddy has an offset to the Pelvis.R.
Can somebody help me? Shall I upload the model, so that you can see it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I should not have used the child of constriction on more than two bones and instead used the copy transforms with additional control bones.